# "start-debugger-server" CLI option not found

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

[According to the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_Desktop)

The CLI option "start-debugger-server" is used to start the server on Firefox. But it does not exist on the Mac version 83.0b5 (64-bit) [Firefox Dev Edition].

The CLI option list:

open: unrecognized option `--start-debugger-server'

Usage: open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-s ][-b ] [-a ] [filenames] [--args arguments]

Help: Open opens files from a shell.
By default, opens each file using the default application for that file.
If the file is in the form of a URL, the file will be opened as a URL.

Options:

```
  -a                Opens with the specified application.
  -b                Opens with the specified application bundle identifier.
  -e                Opens with TextEdit.
  -t                Opens with default text editor.
  -f                Reads input from standard input and opens with TextEdit.
  -F  --fresh       Launches the app fresh, that is, without restoring windows. Saved persistent state is lost, excluding Untitled documents.
  -R, --reveal      Selects in the Finder instead of opening.
  -W, --wait-apps   Blocks until the used applications are closed (even if they were already running).
      --args        All remaining arguments are passed in argv to the application's main() function instead of opened.
  -n, --new         Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running.
  -j, --hide        Launches the app hidden.
  -g, --background  Does not bring the application to the foreground.
  -h, --header      Searches header file locations for headers matching the given filenames, and opens them.
  -s                For -h, the SDK to use; if supplied, only SDKs whose names contain the argument value are searched.
                    Otherwise the highest versioned SDK in each platform is used.
```

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Prepend '--args' to pass in argv...

Example on MacOS:

```
open /Applications/Firefox.app --args --start-debugger-server 6000
```